# Web Service Task in SSIS Error Input tab error

Tags: web-services, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to set up a web Service Task in SSIS,However after setting up the connection properties and then clicking on the input tab to view methods i get this error
**(TITLE: Web Service Task
Could not read the Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file. The input WSDL file is not valid. The following error occurred while reading the file. There is an error in XML document (0, 0)..
)**

Below are the settings i followed to set up the web service task,in case if i doing something wrong.

1. Server URL in HTTP Connection:
   http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL
2. WSDL File field:  Create a temp WSDL file locally
3. Set OverwriteWSDL File to True
4. Click on Download WSDL

All the above steps go smoothly,however when u click on the Input tab in the WEB Service Task Editor,it pops up an error message as mentioned above.

Can anyone has an idea about how to fix this??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link goes to an invalid site which has no XML. I tried using it too when I was learning, the site is not there anymore.

Use this instead: http://holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?WSDL